# How to extract objects from json

Tags: android, android-activity, android-json

I have a scenario where I need only 1 objects out of the entire json.

```
{"id":"1","first_name":"Steve","last_name":"Holt","user_type":"Teacher","user_key_area":"Math"}
```

In above I want to extract user_type.

How will I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to extract the user_type from the json, pass the your json response in place of response variable.

```
JsonObject object =new JsonObject(response);

String user_type = object.getString("user_type");
```

Comment: When I am doing log.d I cant able to find: JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("email", eMail);
    jo.put("password", passWord);

    Log.d("request!", "starting");
    // getting product details by making HTTP request
    String json = jsonParser.postData(LOGIN_URL, jo);

    String jsonData = json.toString();
    Log.d("Data", jsonData);
    
    JSONObject object =new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String userType = object.getString("user_type");
    Log.d("type", userType);
    
    // check your log for json response
    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&) to parse the json response and map it to the model directly . Here is the tutorial for the same [TUTORIAL](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this json in response you can get 1 object like this:

```
String value = response.getString("Key Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Response and that create `JsonObject`

```
JsonObject jsonObject =new JsonObject(res);
```

Create `String` object and pass string parameter "user_type"

```
String userType = jsonObject.getString("user_type");
```

Comment: I am not getting any data while I am doing log.d "String jsonData = json.toString();
    Log.d("Data", jsonData);
    
    JSONObject object =new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String userType = object.getString("user_type");
    Log.d("type", userType);"

Comment: First, you need make proper web call and get data. how you get data?